# How does this program work?

Tags: knowledge, cipher, computer-puzzle

I have coded a Python program. Here's the example of my inputs and outputs:

```
|Input        |Output          |
|-------------|----------------|
|wcf4#        |'gpiyR'         |
|rekvof       |"l`'-l\x08"     |
|Hello!       |'Q`c\\l&'       |
|qwerty       |"d.e\n='"       |
|qwaszx       |'d.0vlg'        |
|1234567890   |'26=ydc5u\n8'   |
|'26=ydc5u\n8'|'[6p9r6dn6cd2i' |
|ErRROr 404   |'J3U\nLpvl/b'   |
|1R4^hg}\?~~~ |'2#wDny$\nF~~~' |
|pythonpython |'.9[=l9\n\\;6up'|
```

How does this program work? You can use a computer and your programming knowledge to find this out.

Somehow you can figure this out with no computer, but that takes a long time.

Python (or JS) code for analysis:

```
{"wcf4#": 'gpiyR', "rekvof": "l`'-l\x08", "Hello!": 'Q`c\\l&', "qwerty": "d.e\n='", "qwaszx": 'd.0vlg', "1234567890": '26=ydc5u\n8', "'26=ydc5u\\n8'": '[6p9r6dn6cd2i', "ErRROr 404": 'J3U\nLpvl/b', "1R4^hg}?~~~": '2#wDny$\nF~~~', "pythonpython": '.9[=l9\n\;6up'}
```

Comment: You don't need to mention the edit summary in the question , people might mistake it for a clue or a hint , its better if you include edit summaries in the edit summary section down below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think:

> Each character is encoded based on it's position in the string, and it's position on a standard(ish) US computer keyboard.
>  I got this mostly from examining the output from "1234567890", the various 4's, and the fact that ~ always encodes to itself.

Explanation:

> Starting with "`" and counting along the rows of the keyboard, assign each key a number. (Including Return, Backspace and Tab but ignoring all other meta keys (Shift, Ctrl, Alt etc.) )
>  (So "`" is 0, "1" is 1, Backspace is 13, Tab is 14, "p" is 24 etc.)
>
>  Then, for each input character, shift it forwards by its position on the keyboard multiplied its position in the input string.
>  E.g. For wcf4#
>
> ```
> Plaintext  Index Keyboard    Shift    Encoded             Encoded
>                  Position             Key Pos             Key
>  w         1     16          1*16=16  32                  g
>  c         2     42          2*42=84  126 (mod 51 = 24)   p
>  f         3     31          3*31=93  124 (mod 51 = 22)   i
>  4         4     4           4*4=16   20                  y
>  #         5     3(shifted)  5*3=15   18                  R (still shifted)
> ```
>
> Other minor things to note:
>   - "~" is in position 0, so always encodes to itself
>   - Shift is sticky, so capitals and shifted punctuation remain capitals or shifted punctuation (like the # above becoming R)